# MVC Updating Partial View with Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The Ajax form does update selected div, but instead of just reloading a partial view in that div it inserts the whole page content into that div.

.cshtml file

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>File(s)</legend>            
    <div id="filesBody">
        @Html.Action("Action", "Controller", new {id=Model.Id})
    </div>
    <br />

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Controller", null, new AjaxOptions {     UpdateTargetId="filesBody"}, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "myForm" }))
    {  
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ComplaintId)
        <div>
            <label for="File">Add File:</label>
            <input type="file" name="FileAttachment" />
            &nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
            @Html.ValidationMessage("FileAttachment")
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
```

Controller

```
public PartialViewResult GetFilesData(long? Id)
{
    Model Model = new Model(Id);
    TryUpdateModel(Model);
    return PartialView(Model);
}
```

Partial view

```
@model Models
<div id="reloadField">
    @foreach (var ph in Model.docs)
    {
        ///code
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `Ajax.BeginForm` be targeting the `GetFilesData` action?

Answer (score 3):

In your partial view set the Layout equal to null.

```
@model Models
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Change your `Ajax.BeginForm` to call the `GetFilesData` action.

Comment: Still inserts whole page into that div

Comment: I don't know if the problem still exists, but unobtrusive javascript should be enabled in web.config and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js should be referenced on page.